# PHP Maximum execution time of 30 seconds

Tags: php, apache

I have a strange problem, my localhost and server has the same `max_execution_time` which is 30 seconds.

But in the server its working without any problem but in the localhost only i am getting the error of Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.

The data set is also same i am using to run.

What are the major items that can cause `max_execution_time` exceeded error?

PHP settings on server

```
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    128M    128M
```

PHP settings on localhost

```
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    128M    128M
```

Can the RAM of the computer and Ram of the Server cause this problem ? if so the only difference is i have a 8 gb ram in my computer and 2 gb ram in the server.

Comment: Could it simply be down to computation speed? Spec differences? Network differences (if it does stuff that uses the network)? Etc etc. So many different possibilities.

Comment: Infinite loops, different configurations, network restrictions, slow connections to database, etc..... you need to narrow down exactly what is taking the time, otherwise your question is way too vague and lacking in any useful detail because we don't have any clue what your script does, or how your server is set up to do it

Comment: running xdebug? thatll slow you by about x4 in a dev environment

Comment: Its the same network.

Comment: @DevDonkey no not running xdebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the exact same code is used on both machines, your issue either is the CPU / processing speed of your machine (less likely) or the amount of data your code is processing (more likely).

Strictly speaking however, if your code is hitting the max execution time, you should be looking at reducing the amount of processing your code does in one execution. If your code is build to handle / process a large amount of requests, consider adding a maximum amount of data to process in one request to stagger / batch process them instead. (E.g. Instead of processing 100 rows/requests at once, set a cap at 25 and stagger it over 4 executions of your code).

If it's one large process, you may instead want to look at increasing the cap on your maximum execution time instead.

Comment: Yes, i have done a batch process like you mentioned. but my question is why to process the same no of data in localhost i get that maximum execution time but not in the server while both has same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly your request is taking longer on your local machine than on a server - if you imagine, your server is only doing a very few jobs - your desktop machine is running a GUI, other background software, your IDE etc - so even if they had identical hardware (and the reality is your server probably has enterprise-grade hardware (faster disks etc), whereas your desktop is consumer-grade hardware), so even something as simple as querying a database will almost certainly take longer on your local setup.

As such, it's not a 'like-for-like' test.